# Does there always exist a prime $q\equiv3\mod 4$ that divides $p+a^2$ with $p\equiv1$ mod 4

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p\equiv1\mod4$.  Is it true that there will always exist a prime $q$ that satisfies $q\vert(p+a^2)$ and $q\equiv3\mod4$, for some integer $a$?

I have tried proceeding by contradiction, assuming that for every prime $q$ such that $q\vert(p+a^2)$ it must satisfy $q\equiv1\mod4$, however I have not been able to find a contradiction. Is this even true, and is it a much more complicated proof than I think? It seems to me like it must be true as there are infinitely many primes congruent to 3 modulo 4.

Comment: I think the question is not clear.   I believe you are asking:  "Given a prime $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ does there exist a prime $q\equiv 3\pmod 4$ such that $q$ divides $p+a^2$ for some integer $a$".  In any case, that's the question I attempted to answer below.

Comment: Yes that was the question I was asking, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  $q\equiv -1 \pmod 4$,  By quadratic reciprocity we have $$\left(\frac {-p}q\right)=\left(\frac {-1}q\right)\times\left(\frac qp\right)=-\left(\frac qp\right)$$

So choose any quadratic non-residue $n$  $\pmod p$ and let $q$ be a prime satisfying $$q\equiv n\pmod p\quad \&\quad q\equiv -1\pmod 4$$  (infinitely many such $q$ exist by Dirichlet's Theorem).  It follows that $q$ is of the form you want.

Comment: I figured this question related to quadratic reciprocity, but, wait, doesn't $\left(\frac pq\right)=\left(\frac qp\right)$ if $p\equiv1\pmod4$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Yes, but I omitted the $-1$ multiplier for $p$.  I will edit.  The congruence $p+a^2\equiv 0 \pmod q$ is the same as requiring that $-p$ is a square $\pmod q$.

Comment: because it's $a^2+p$ not $a^2-p\equiv0\pmod q$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Right.  We have $a^2\equiv -p \pmod q$ so we need $\left(\frac {-p}q\right)=1$, which ends up being the same as requiring that $\left( \frac qp\right)=-1$.

Comment: I got it, @lulu, thanks; +$1$